# Why does Matchers.hasItem return a Matcher<Iterable<? super T>>, but Matchers.contains return Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>>?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

In hamcrest, [`Matchers.hasItem`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItem-T-) and friends returns a `Matcher<Iterable<? super T>>`, but [`contains`](https://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.2/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#contains-E...-) and friends returns a `Matcher<Iterable<? extends T>>`. Why the difference?

Answer (score 0):

My (handwavy) understanding is that the root cause is [Naming of method Matchers#contains is ambiguous #140](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/issues/140)

> In code reviews here, people often misread this:
>
> ```java
> assertThat(collection, contains("x"));
> ```
>
> As meaning this: "Assert that the collection contains 'x'".
>
> But what it actually means is this: "Assert that the collection contains only 'x'".
>
> This causes a lot of unnecessary questions to be raised on our code reviews where code was updated to use Hamcrest, just because it reads differently to what it's actually doing.
>
> At the same time, people looking to write new code with Hamcrest are using autocompletion to find appropriate-looking methods, and will often try to use contains before discovering that they really wanted hasItem.
>
> I would suggest containsOnly as a new name, but containsInAnyOrder sort of has the same issue and I am finding it hard to jam the additional word in there.

Thus given:

```java
class BaseFoo {}
class Foo1 extends BaseFoo {}
class Foo2 extends BaseFoo {}

Foo1 foo1 = new Foo1();
Foo2 foo2 = new Foo2();

Matcher<Iterable<? extends BaseFoo>> containsMatcher = Matchers.contains(foo1, foo2);
Matcher<Iterable<? super Foo1>> hasItemsMatcher = Matchers.hasItem(foo1);
```

- containsMatcher will never match on an Iterable containing superclasses of BaseFoo
- hasItemsMatcher can possibly match on an Iterable containing superclasses of BaseFoo

Also note that `Matcher` interface does not use its generic argument in its member methods (particularly in matches which accepts Object) - generic argument only matters when combining the Matchers.